# iPhoneX can not show launch image well?

Tags: ios-simulator, ios11, xcode9, iphone-x

[image]

I add 1125x2436 launch image as left for iPhoneX. However, I get the strange result in simulator as right. I have not idea what causes that.

**Update:**

[image]

I found that is "Landscape" launch image be read on iPhoneX simulator, and not "Portrait". Even my app is set "Portrait" Device Orientation only. If I remove the "Landscape" launch image, and app seem use the "Portrait" image instead while it can not found the "Landscape" image. I still not idea how to fix it.

Comment: having similar problems... Apple launch a new device and new screen aspect and spectacularly fail to provide the tools to support it...